# left or forgotten?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I'd like to know whether **left** or **forgotten** is correct in the following:

> The librarian always goes all around the library before closing time in case someone has **left** / **forgotten** something.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Both words are fine.

However, if you use *left* you would normally add *behind* to the phrase.

So:

> . . . in case someone has forgotten something.
>    . . . in case someone has left something behind.

---

As a more general comment, it would be more natural to say:

> . . . before closing time in order to (see / check) if someone . . .

Using *in case someone* gives a slightly odd meaning to the sentence.

Comment: What about "in case anyone has left behind their belongings"? Would you still find "in case" odd?

Comment: Only slightly, and only upon analysis. The issue is that *in case someone x* makes the sentence sound like *because someone might have x*. But while *because* doesn't require something extra, *in case* does in order to be complete. (*In case someone left something behind* ***and it needed to be returned***.)